# Association among three model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these models with association as follows

```
class User
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :country
end

class Country
  has_many :users
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belong_to :user
  belong_to :country
end
```

Comment has `user_id` and `country_id` as column name.
User has `country_id` as column name.

Now if i write this code is console

```
User.first.comments.create :content=>"some content"
```

This would create a comment but `country_id` column of Comment would be null. I want `country_id` to be filled based on `user_id`
How can i do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `country` based on `user` with `before_save` or `before_create` callbacks. This could help you:

```
class User
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :country
end

class Country
  has_many :users
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belong_to :user
  belong_to :country

  before_create :set_country

  def set_country
    self.country_id = user.country_id if user 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Will the comment always have the same country as the user? If so do you really need that relation at all? You could just infer the country of the comment from the country of the user that made it.

```
Class Comment
  delegate :country, to: :user
end
```

`comment.country` will then automatically return `comment.user.country`

Answer (score 1):

you have to explicitely pass the `country_id`:

```
@user = User.first
@user.comments.create(:content=>"some content", country_id: @user.country)
```

Comment: cant it be done through association without passing country_id explicitly

Comment: @rohankharvi then you can do it using callbacks `before_save` or `before_create` in your model as @MaximPontyushenko has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
u = User.first
u.comments.create(content: "Some comment", country_id: u.country.id)
```